# Why my DateFormat is 2021-02-18T09:58:09.151493

Tags: c#, html, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to change `DateFormat` to `2021-02-18T09:58`and I add in my model in DateTime field

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Also in my `Create.cshtml` View I add `asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}"` but still have problem.
Since I use datatable I also try to render this dateformat in client-side by doesn't work.
Can someone tell me where I made mistake ? What is wrong this this DataAnnotation ?

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});


function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "title", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "description", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%", "dateFormat": "mm/dd/yy" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Upsert/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> 
                                </a>
                                <a onclick=Delete("/Manager/Ticket/Delete/${data}") class="btn btn-danger text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "25%"
            }
        ]
    });
}


function Delete(url) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to Delete?",
        text: "You will not be able to restore the data!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        toastr.success(data.message);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also here in my my `IndexPage` where DateTime should be display as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm

```
@model VmSTicketing.Models.Ticket
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista svih tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>DateAndTime</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/ticket.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ is not enough of a problem description. How does it "not work". What do you expect and what do you actually get? Or do you get errors? If so, what are they and where are they thrown? ...

Comment: I get DateFormat like `2021-02-18T09:58:09.151493` but I want something like this `2021-02-18T09:58`
I don't get any errors

Comment: Ah, it's in the title ... right, sorry.

Comment: Read post carefully one more time :)

Comment: `DisplayFormatAttribute` is processed by `@Html.DisplayFor` during cshtml rendering. Your code fills `tblTable` from javascript code on client side, so setting`DisplayFormat` useless for you. It looks like you are using jquery UI DataTables for filling the html table. It looks you are mixing things in it's initialization: `width`, `format`, `render` parts should be in `columnDefs` not in `columns`. See [How to format date in table cell](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42601/how-to-format-date-in-table-cell)